# Opening a window in aspx using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using the below code to open a new window while the function return the success message. At the same time i want to close the self window. Now am getting the error:

> newwindow is not defined

```
 var value = getQueryStrings();
 var cust_id = value["cust_id"];
 try {

     PageMethods.add_plan_items(unescape(items), cust_id, device, OnGetMessageSuccess, OnGetMessageFailure);

 } catch (ex) {
     alert(ex);
 }

 function OnGetMessageSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
     try {
         var ret_array = result.toString().split(':');
         if (ret_array[0] == "Success Alert ") {

             var left = (screen.width / 2) - 1015 / 2;
             var top = (screen.height / 2) - 550 / 2;

             self.close(); //Close the opened window

             //Enter here and self window is closed

             var newwindow = window.open('test.aspx?id=Y&cust_id=' + cust_id, 'Add Items', 'height=550,width=1000,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,left=' + left + ', top=' + top + ',screenX=' + left + ',screenY=' + top + '');
             if (window.focus) {
                 newwindow.focus()
             }
             return false;
         } else {
             self.close(); //Close the opened window
             alert('Error Alert : Error for adding plans in your specified device. Please try again later!');
         }

     } catch (ex) {
         alert(ex);
     }

 }

 function OnGetMessageFailure(error, userContext, methodName) {
     alert(error.get_message());
 }
```

Comment: close parent after opening the child window.

Answer (score 0):

Don't close your parent window first
Save the parent window, then open your child window (new window) and then close your parent window

```
var parentWindow = self.window;
var newWindow = window.open(...);

parentWindow.close();
```

Comment: `newwindow`   in your original code w is small and in my code w is in capital. Change that

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now i change the newwindow instead of newWindow. But i met a new error control must be in the control tree of a page.